# Extracting Elements from Array

Tags: python, numpy

From a given array, extract all the elements which are greater than 'm' and less than 'n'. Note: 'm' and 'n' are integer values provided as input.

Input format:

A list of integers on line one

Integer 'm' on line two

Integer 'n' on line three

Output format:

1-D array containing integers greater than 'm' and smaller than 'n'.

Sample input:

[ 1, 5, 9, 12, 15, 7, 12, 9 ] (array)

6 (m)

12 (n)

Sample output:

[ 9 7 9 ]

Sample input:

[ 1, 5, 9, 12, 15, 7, 12, 9 ]

12

6

Sample output:

[ ]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you _also_ demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that is to include the **text** version of the source code you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job.

take 2 input in int format. then iterate over the given array and put a if condition like below :-

```
arr  = [ 1, 5, 9, 12, 15, 7, 12, 9 ]

max = int(input("Max : "))

min = int(input("Min : "))

output = []
for a in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[a] > max and arr[a] < min :
        print(arr[a])
        output.append(arr[a])
```

Comment: Since you are iterating it's index, it should  be `arr[a]` instead of `a`. `if arr[a] > max and arr[a] < min : output.append(arr[a])`

Comment: @sittsering :  I agree, it should not be index, instead it should be arr element. Updated above

Answer (score 0):

Make the array (not a list!)

```
In [857]: x = np.array([ 1, 5, 9, 12, 15, 7, 12, 9 ])
```

test against the lower bound:

```
In [858]: x>6
Out[858]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

and the upper:

```
In [859]: x<12
Out[859]: array([ True,  True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

combine them:

```
In [860]: (x>6)&(x<12)
Out[860]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Use that as a boolean mask to select elements from `x`:

```
In [861]: mask = (x>6)&(x<12)
In [862]: x[mask]
Out[862]: array([9, 7, 9])
```